# Implementing mean filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

I have done the question by searching here on stack but I'm here to ask what's the difference between what I was previously doing and what I've done now which works.

So we have an assignment and we're supposed to implement a mean filter and the way I was going about it was first converting the image to an `m`x`n` format (`x`) and then creating the filter matrix (`h`) of some order e.g. 3x3. Then I went on to convolve the x and h to apply the filter to the image but this didn't work and I want to know the reason.

The code in comments is the one which I implemented and did't work and the rest of the code works. By the way, the image I'm using here is the koala image in windows 7.

```
color = imread('Koala.jpg');
grey = rgb2gray(color);
figure
imshow(grey)
h = fspecial('average',5);
I = imfilter(grey, h);
figure
imshow(I)

% result = conv2(grey,h);
% figure
% imshow(result)
```

So why does `conv2` not work and `imfilter` does? The requirement of the assignment was to use `fspecial` for the `h` and `conv2` to implement the filter and with the `conv2` method all I get is a white image with spots of black at some points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### what went wrong?

It seems like you input `grey` of type `uint8` to `conv2`, but you get a result of type `double`. The range of the values of each pixel in the result image is [0..255], when you `imshow` an image of type `double` `imshow` expects pixel values in the range [0..1] and thus saturates the pixels at 1. As a result of this behavior of `imshow` the output of `imshow(result)` is completely white.
On the other hand, `imfilter` gives you a result of type `uint8` and `imshow` has no problem with the pixel intensities of this type.

#### what can you do?

The simplest thing is to tell `imshow` to detect the proper range for pixel values:

```
imshow( result, [] );
```

Another solution would be to convert `grey` to double using `im2double`, or converting the result to `uint8`.

Comment: Thanks that worked .. But can you please tell me what do the brackets [ ] indicate in the map parameter of imshow ??

Comment: Read about [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html) especially the part on `'DisplayRange'`. @ Hameem